# MySQL trigger issue - is it working properly?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains column of type DATE, now i want to create trigger after insert, which deletes all the past rows from the database.

My trigger looks like this:
`CREATE TRIGGER deletePastNotesAfterInsert AFTER INSERT ON tableofnotes  FOR EACH ROW  DELETE FROM tableofnotes WHERE deadLine < CURRENT_DATE();`

The problem is that whenever I try to insert something, it is automatically deleted, which should not be in case the date is not past. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Check if your inserts are returning an error. AFAIK you can't modify the same table that the trigger got triggered on.

Comment: @vatev is correct. I suggest you create an event to purge the rows you don't want.

Comment: It automatically gets deleted? is that the case? or it never gets inserted?

Comment: @vatev's comment was true, that was the case. Thank you.